# Let $f(x)=\frac{x^4-\alpha x^3-3x^2+3\alpha x}{x-\alpha}$. If the range of $ f(x)$ is the set of entire real numbers, what is $\alpha$?

Tags: functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTH0S.jpg)

For the function $$\frac{x^4-\alpha x^3-3x^2+3\alpha x}{x-\alpha}$$ the numerator can be factorised and hence the term in denominator gets cancelled. So how can we get $\alpha$ when $x-\alpha$ gets cancelled ???

Comment: please check the link below title for the question image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such problems, precision is needed. When you say "gets cancelled", you are not completely right, and that slight imprecision ruins the whole point of the problem.

In fact, the function is $\frac{x-\alpha}{x-\alpha} (x^3-3x)$. 
You cannot cancel the fraction $\frac{x-\alpha}{x-\alpha}$, because for $x=\alpha$ it is not $1$ (but undefined).

But of course, the above transformation leads to the solution, and it is a very important observation. The function $g(x)=x^3-3x$ is strictly monotone increasing on $]-\infty, -1]$ and $[1, \infty[$. It is decreasing on $[-1,1]$, where its range is $[-2,2]$. On the other two intervals, the same range $[-2,2]$ is attained on $[-2,-1]$ and on $[1,2]$. Clearly, $g(x)$ is surjective.

Now back to the actual function: when you have $\frac{x-\alpha}{x-\alpha} g(x)$ rather than $g(x)$, the difference is that you make the function not defined at $\alpha$. So the question is: for what $\alpha$ is it true that killing the function $g(x)= x^3-3x$ at $\alpha$, it is still surjective? In other words, for what $\alpha$ is it true that the function $g(x)= x^3-3x$ attains the value $g(\alpha)$ at some point different from $\alpha$.

By the above analysis, the answer is $\alpha\in [-2,2]$.

Comment: ok i  understood the graph but how do you use the fact that the range is set of entire real numbers??

Comment: the range of which function?